# In Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, only Spacebar tab is not working in terminal window. how to fix it?

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, system-installation, updates, keyboard

I have upgraded Ubuntu version from 18.04 to 20.04. When i opened my terminal window, to execute any command, than i noticed that keyboard space-bar button is not working.
Earlier i was facing the same problem in 18.04 version also, but in 18.04, i was able to use space bar button in terminal window with (Microsoft icon key+space bar).
But now, it is not working even with any key combination.

now i can only do copy-paste commands from notepad to terminal and than execute. :(

Comment: We cannot see your system, and I don't understand what you mean by "space-bar tab", "not working", "working only with ...". How could I even start to recreate this problem?

Comment: Issue updated. Please suggest any solution.